# Creating model objects from raw form data - is a one-to-one field match required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webforms, model, controller

If I say this in the controller:

```
@order = Order.new(params[:order])
```

What is required for this to work?

Does there need to be a one-to-one match between all of the fields in `params[:order]` and the Order model?

Or can there be more or fewer fields in `params[:order]` than are required to instantiate an Order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

params[:order] itself should be a hash, where each key is the name of the model field.  To see how Rails converts form field names into the params hash, write a view template with the form_for helper and view source.

There can be more or fewer fields, yes.  Extra fields will be ignored.  Fewer fields just won't be copied into the instance object.  You don't need anything at all to instantiate an ActiveRecord object.  (Object validity and saving are a different story - they invoke validations and the ActiveRecord callback mechanism.)

Comment: Ok, so there's no problem instantiating the object - the problems you may encounter are when you try to save or update. In that case having fewer fields may violate a database requirement but not until then.

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  Validations don't run until you save an object or call .valid? or .invalid.  More here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html

Answer (score 1):

There can indeed be fewer fields.

Make sure you have all fields necessary for any validations though!

Comment: Could there also be more fields in the form than in the model? Would ActiveRecord just ignore the extraneous ones?